# Trying to run a simple php script on MediaTemple server using a Cron job

Tags: php, cron, mediatemple

Disclaimer: I have very little experience with any of this.

My script looks like this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('test_php.txt', 'hmm');
```

And the command in my cron job looks like this

```
php php_test.php
```

Nothing is getting written to my root directory. I've used Cron to back up my databases using mysqldump, so I'm familiar with how to set up a cron job. I'm specifically having trouble running a php script this way.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the location that you're writing to? In addition, the CLI provides an error log.

Comment: It's the root of my server, so I believe so. I can write sql files using mysqldump. My php script is in root, and I'm trying to write my file in root. From what I've read, when I start writing actual scripts I need to use absolute paths for every directory, but right now I'm just trying to get this simple thing to work.

Comment: Expanding on last comment might need to change the 'working directory'/ `chdir/getcwd`... Might wanna `which php` too jsut to be sure or in the cron use `/user/bin/php` or whatever.